# Why are some videos on ros.org private?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ,

why videos are private in many pages of ros website

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53373/why-are-some-videos-on-ros.org-private?/) by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-01-25**:
Which videos?

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-01-25**:
here http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/Looking%20at%20Camera%20Data

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-01-25**:
It looks like that video isn't private, it's been deleted. Are there any others?

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-01-25**:
Yes
this also
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gOBQc6z03E&feature=player_embedded
And also, there are more than one, but not many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably because whoever posted it did not realize it was private.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-27**:
It was probably contributed by a community member and who's account has changed settings.